# Problem with a GUID subscribedSkus on the Microsoft Graph API with the SDK in C#

Tags: c#, azure, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to retrieve information from this API endpoint:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscribedsku-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp

But I have a problem during execution, it gives me this error:

> ODataError: Invalid object identifier. It must be a string in the form of [Guid]_[Guid].

And yet I send him a GUID in String

Here is my code :

```
public async Task<SubscribedSku> GetAvailableLicenceDetails(string idSku)
{
            try
            {
                string accessToken = await tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(new string[] { "Organization.Read.All" });
                var authenticationProvider = new BaseBearerTokenAuthenticationProvider(new TokenProvider(accessToken));

                var graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(authenticationProvider);

                var SubscribedSku = await graphServiceClient.SubscribedSkus[idSku].GetAsync();

                return SubscribedSku;
            }
            catch (ODataError odataError)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(odataError.Error.Code);
                Console.WriteLine(odataError.Error.Message);
                throw;
            }
}

var sku = await GetAvailableLicenceDetails("6fd2c87f-b296-42f0-b197-1e91e994b900");
```

I tried to find the problem but I can't, I need help !

Thank you

Comment: Only to confirm, has idSku format like guid_guid? Two guids separated by the underscore?

Comment: No, the only id I have is a classic Guid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to retrieve subscribed sku by `skuId` (id of the service SKU)

Check the properties in the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/subscribedsku?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties)

| Property | Description |
| --- | --- |
| id | The unique identifier for the subscribed sku object |
| skuId | The unique identifier (GUID) for the service SKU |

The call `await graphServiceClient.SubscribedSkus["id"].GetAsync();` requires `id` not `skuId`.

The limitation of the subscribedSkus is that they don't support filtering by `skuId`, so you can't use

```
var result = await graphClient.SubscribedSkus.GetAsync((requestConfiguration) =>
{
    requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Filter = $"skuId eq {idSku}";
});
```

Only way is to retrieve all subscribedskus and perform filter on the client

```
var response = await graphServiceClient.SubscribedSkus.GetAsync();
var subscribedSku = response.Value.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.SkuId eq idSku);
```

Or you have id not skuId, you can retrieve the specific subscribed sku

```
var SubscribedSku = await graphServiceClient.SubscribedSkus[id].GetAsync();
```